# How to connect 64+ light sensors to a board?

Tags: pi-3, connection, connectors

Making a robot to play chess with physically. I've embedded light sensors into the board but I'm not sure how to manage that much input? What would I need to manage each input individually. (Rasp Pi3)

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: some sort of multiplexer